# Can I freely assign an address within a provided /64 IPv6 range? How does routing work?

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

My VPS provider assigned my VPS a /64 IPv6 range. The host was dynamically assigned an address in that range using its MAC address for the /64.

Can I statically assign the ::1 address within that range to my host (for use with DNS)? If so, how will outside hosts discover the route? Is there anything else I have to do to have the host propagate the information?

(I tried and it seemed to work, but there were delays of a couple of seconds initially when trying to ping the host remotely, and the setup has since stopped working so I wonder if I was doing it properly.)

Comment: It depends on how your VPS configured their side. Can you share more information?

Comment: The control panel shows assigned IPv6 a:b:c:d::1 (/64) and a gateway in the same /48. What sort of other information would help?

Comment: The VPS provider's name would be useful.

Comment: Ah, sorry. That's TransIP(.nl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are several possible situations:

1. Your server "owns" a `/64` range in a *big* shared `/48` subnet. From the router's perspective, all addresses are on-link and have to be individually discovered via NDP. This is (sadly) the most common situation in cheaper VPSes.
2. Your server "owns" a *single* address in a shared `/64` subnet, but *additionally* has a dedicated "routed" `/64` subnet (but possibly larger, like `/56`). From the router's perspective, only that single address is on-link, and the dedicated subnet is routed *via* that address. This is more flexible.

From [TransIP's documentation](https://www.transip.eu/knowledgebase/article/145-ipv6-address-bladevps-windows-server/), it definitely looks like they're doing option #1.

(Also in general, if your control panel shows a gateway outside your /64, you're probably seeing option #1. If your control panel asks you to add *individual* IP addresses, that's very likely option #1 – unless it's purely for reverse-DNS purposes. But e.g. SolusVM-based panels don't even let you specify rDNS, only the address itself, so that's clearly a sign of variant #1.)

> Can I statically assign the ::1 address within that range to my host (for use with DNS)?

If the subnet is routed, yes. The entire routed prefix (be it a /64 or different size) is in your control.

If it's on-link, depends on the provider. Technically yes, you could, *but* many providers use the SolusVM software for managing the services, and it appears to reserve that address for unclear reasons; i.e. the "Add new IPv6 address" button doesn't allow adding it.

> If so, how will outside hosts discover the route?

If the host thinks it's within the same subnet as you, it will use NDP (the IPv6 equivalent of ARP) to find out your MAC address directly. (NDP will be used whether the subnet is routed or not, but the address being queried will differ.)

But the rest of the internet won't bother with discovering anything; they will simply forward the packet to their default gateway (again using NDP), and let the gateway deal with it.

In general, the internet doesn't need a route to you specifically – it only needs a route to the VPS provider's whole network, that's all.

> Is there anything else I have to do to have the host propagate the information?

No, technically all it needs is respond to NDP "Neighbour Solicitations", which is automatic as long as the address is configured in the OS.

Exception: In some situations (when you want to "announce" an on-link address, but don't want to configure it in the OS), you need to configure a "proxy NDP" daemon to send those responses. For example, you'd do this when the host doesn't provide you with a routed subnet, but you still need to set up a VPN server.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is immensely helpful. Precisely the sort of insight I was looking for.